# Swift json parsing using generics

Tags: ios, json, swift, generics

I have response coming like this from web service. for this I use JSON generator and generator provide me 3 classes, one with named message, second with data and third with category.

the issue for me is that now backend team want to follow same structure in all over the app for all the services, that means data rigntnow contains category object, for second service data will contains deal object and so on.

so what is the best way to fix this issue:

1> should I take json response from inside data and fetch it.

2> is there any way to make generic in mobData class so it can accept any type of object like category, deals.

please find below service response.

```
{
    "message": {
        "code": "200",
        "status": "success",
        "message": "Deals Retrieved"
    },
    "data": {
  "category": [
    {
      "categoryId": 0,
      "categoryName": "Health",
      "categoryIcon": "icon.png",
      "categorySelectedIcon": "icon.png",
      "subCategory": [
        {
          "subCategoryId": 0,
          "subCategoryName": "Hospitals",
          "subCategoryCounts": 20
        },
        {
          "subCategoryId": 1,
          "subCategoryName": "Pharmacies",
          "subCategoryCounts": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "categoryId": 1,
      "categoryName": "Education",
      "categoryIcon": "icon.png",
      "categorySelectedIcon": "icon.png": [
        {
          "subCategoryId": 0,
          "subCategoryName": "Universities",
          "subCategoryCounts": 16
        },
        {
          "subCategoryId": 1,
          "subCategoryName": "Institues",
          "subCategoryCounts": 14
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Comment: Actually, the change should be done on the backend side and  "data" should keep the actual object instead of being nested. I.e. for one service the "data" must be an array of categories, and for another service the same "data" must be an array of deal objects. In other words, the "data" field should **be** (and **not contain**) an array of objects, which that service is related to.

Comment: the issue with the backend team is that they prepared same service for portal and mobile and rightnow unable to change this. so i have to deal with this.